# Enabling Inline Editing for Social Post Tab on Radian6 App

Tags: servicecloud, inlineeditsupport, social-contacts

We currently use Radian6 and ServiceCloud integrated.

We would like to enable "inline editing" feature on "social posts" tab to be able to process social posts faster.

I am aware that a list should contain single record type to be able to enable inline editing. I experienced this on some other tabs in SFDC. However, though there are 3 social posts record types as following facebook, twitter and other, I cannot filter sources listed in tab. Because there is no record type filter option in edit view section on social posts.

How can we filter record types in social posts tab to enable inline editing? Any experience or recommendations would be welcome.

Thanks